# Prove the following sets equalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm really struggling with proofes, please tell me if I'm correct and if there is a better way to prove (or disprove) the following:

i) $(A \setminus B) \setminus B = A \setminus B$

My answer: $x\in((A \setminus B)\setminus B) \Leftrightarrow x\in (A \setminus B)$ and $x\notin B \Leftrightarrow x\in A$ and $ x \notin B \Leftrightarrow x\in (A \setminus B)$

ii) $A - (B - A) = A$

My answer: $x\in (A \setminus (B \setminus A)) \Leftrightarrow x\in A$ and $x\notin (B \setminus A) \Leftrightarrow x\in A$

iii) $P(A \cup B) = P(A) \cup P(B)$

My answer: not true. The case where $A=\{3\}$ and $B=\{5\}$, $P(A\cup B) = \{\emptyset,\{3\},\{5\},\{3,5\}\}$ and $P(A) \cup P(B) = \{\emptyset,\{3\},\{5\}\}$

iv) $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cap P(B)$

My answer: $x\in P(A\cap B) \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq (A\cap B) \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq A $ and $ x\subseteq B \Leftrightarrow x \in P(A)$ and $x\in P(B) \Leftrightarrow x \in (P(A) \cap P(B))$

Comment: These look great to me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your answers look perfectly fine.

I would only be slightly more detailed in ${\rm ii.}$, where you make the leap:
$$x \in A \land x \notin B \setminus A \iff x \in A$$
which could do with some more justification, e.g. noting that:
$$x \notin B \setminus A \iff x \notin B \lor x \in A$$
after which the result follows from the logical law of absorption:
$$\alpha \land (\alpha\lor\beta)\equiv \alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

Other way to prove (ii):
$$A \setminus (B \setminus A)=A\cap(B\cap A^c)^c=A\cap(B^c\cup A) = A$$

> First equality follows from this fact: for $T$ and $S$, sets we have $T \setminus S=T\cap S^c$. Second is by De Morgan's laws. Third because: if $T\subset S$ then $T\cap S = T$